# Firebase Lite issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I install firebase using npm install firebase ,also tried using latest firebase version,but i was not able use complete firebase sdk ,it install firebase lite version
import { Timestamp, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/';:-This import gives me error

import { Timestamp, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';  :-This import is working for me

but because of this i am not not able to use onsnapshot method as it is not supported in firebase lite

Help me to resolve this isuue

Comment: It is really hard to follow what the problem is. Instead of telling us about the Firebase lite workaround, please edit your question to show the minimal, complete code snippet that doesn't work, and the exact error message you get. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.